# Export Broken Links records as CSV/XLS

Tags: 8, importing-exporting

In Drupal 8 I can see the list of broken links at `Administration->Configuration->System->Broken Link`.
It is showing thousands of records with pagination.

I'm using [Broken Link](http://drupal.org/project/broken_link) Module.

Is there any way we can export the entire record as a CSV or XLS file?

Comment: Are you using the Link Checker module? https://www.drupal.org/project/linkchecker

Comment: I am using https://www.drupal.org/project/broken_link this module

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Broken Link module seems to have views support, so you can use the [Views Data Export module](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_data_export) and a View of the data to export it.

If you'd prefer to go directly to the database, the module stores information in a table called `broken_link` so you can query that and use tools to move database results into a csv/excel if you'd like.

Comment: I could not create a view with the broken link content. I think this module does not support the views. I have requested the feature in the module. But as of now, I am going to take the report from the database.

Comment: @siddiq OK, perhaps you could upvote or accept my answer? :)

Comment: I upvoted. Is my question worth to have an upvote? ;)